# Understanding SystemTime::now() behavior

Tags: rust, time

I have the following code

```
use std::time::{Duration, SystemTime};
use std::thread::sleep;


fn main() {

    let now = SystemTime::now();
    let delayed_now = now + Duration::from_secs(10);
  
   let x = delayed_now.duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs()-(now).duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs();
   
   let sleep_time = Duration::from_secs(x);
   
   sleep(sleep_time);
   
   
   let new_now = SystemTime::now();
   if delayed_now > new_now {
       println!("ohno");
   }
 
}
```

I'm wondering if `delayed_now` can ever be bigger than `new_now`. Is this even possible? (assuming the leap seconds edge case doesn't exist).

Running it on playground doesn't trigger the condition to True.

My feeling is that it *should* be possible for delayed_now to be bigger, given that information about nanoseconds is lost. But I can't verify it.

Comment: You can change your clock when sleeping. SystemTime is not monotonic.

Comment: @KamilCuk but this is only for leap seconds edge case, right? It's usually monotonic barring edge cases, right? Or is the monotonicity non-derterminstic?

Comment: No, this also applies if you go into your operating system settings and change the time or if ntp gradually adjust the computers time to it's source etc.

Comment: `but this is only for leap seconds edge case, right?` Noooo, you click on the clock in your desktop and set the clock. What you set will change SystemTime

Answer (score 1):

First, this line

```rs
let x = delayed_now.duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs()-(now).duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs();
```

will always be 10. Mathematically, this is

```rs
delayed_now - SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH - (now - SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH)
```

which you can simplify to

```rs
delayed_now - now
```

And since you just defined `delayed_now` as `now + 10`, this will evaluate to 10. You can just do `sleep(Duration::from_secs(10))`.

Next, the doc for [`sleep`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep.html) says this:

> The thread may sleep longer than the duration specified due to scheduling specifics or platform-dependent functionality. It will never sleep less.

That means that this code should never panic:

```rs
let later = Instant::now() + Duration::from_secs(10);
sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
assert!(Instant::now() >= later);
```

However, 10 seconds in `Instant` is not 10 seconds in `SystemTime`. `sleep` probably measures time in the same way `Instant` does, but it definitely doesn't measure the way `SystemTime` does. `Instant` can speed up and slow down, and this might not be reflected in `SystemTime`, so if you happen to measure a particularly speedy 10 seconds of `Instant`, it could take less than 10 seconds of `SystemTime` (this may only appear on certain OSes or hardware). Then of course, if `SystemTime` is ever rolled back, whether by daylight saving time, synchronizing with network time, or manually by the user, it can report less than 10 seconds.